# bash script get result from test into variable

Tags: shell-script, variable, test

I'm trying to learn Bash scripting and for fun I would like to write a script which will monitor the `httpd.service`.

The basic construct looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVICE=httpd.service

if [ "systemctl show -p ActiveState $SERVICE | sed 's/ActiveState=//g'" != "active" ] && [ "systemctl show -p SubState $SERVICE | sed 's/SubState=//g'"  != "running" ]
then
        echo "$SERVICE is inactive" | mailx -r admin@server.com -s "$SERVICE not running on $HOSTNAME"  my_account@server.com
fi
```

it works. Whether is written in a secure and best practice way, I guess not but its my second day and I first need to get an idea behind scripting in generall.

How can I get the result of the two `test`conditions in a variable so that I could print the status and substatus in to the mail ? I guess I could do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE=httpd.service

STATE=$(systemctl show -p ActiveState $SERVICE | sed 's/ActiveState=//g')
SUBSTATE=$(systemctl show -p SubState $SERVICE | sed 's/SubState=//g')

if [ "$STATE" != "active" ] && [ "SUBSTATE" != "running" ]
then
        echo "$SERVICE state is $STATE and substate is $SUBSTATE"
fi
```

But not sure if this is a elegant way to do this ?

**EDIT**

Thanks for all your valuable comments! I've up voted all of them!

So, basically I ended up doing it in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE=httpd.service
HOST=$(grep '^ServerName' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | sed 's/^.* //')
EMAIL=blablatrace@blabla.com




if [ "$(systemctl show -p ActiveState $SERVICE | sed 's/ActiveState=//g')" = "active" ]
then
        echo "$SERVICE is running" >/dev/null
else
        systemctl restart $SERVICE 2>/dev/null
        if [ "$(systemctl show -p ActiveState $SERVICE | sed 's/ActiveState=//g')" = "active" ]
        then
                echo "$SERVICE on $HOST has been started" | mailx -r "${HOST}"@blabla.com -s "$SERVICE on $HOST restarted" $EMAIL
        else
                echo "$SERVICE on $HOST is stopped and could not be started!" | mailx -r "${HOST}"@blabla.com -s "$SERVICE on $HOST has encountered a problem!" $EMAIL
        fi
fi
```

Could you please have a look at it? Are there any style, not POSIX compliant things used ?

Comment: @RoVo, you want `if [ "$(cmd)" ...`, with the quotes.

Comment: `systemctl show --value -p ActiveState` to avoid having to use `sed`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you! yes but if you are on systemd version 240 and higher :) https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS I'm on 219.

Answer (score 2):

Your first script doesn't work, you need

```
if [ "$(cmd)" != "active" ]
```

instead of

```
if [ "cmd" != "active" ]
```

---

The second script looks good.
Take care about negated conditions combined with `&&`. It might not give the result your looking for. I think you want `||` instead of `&&`.

You don't need the `g` option to `sed` substitution here, but it doesn't hurt either.

---

But it would be more elegant if you'd use the `systemctl` integrated functions:

```
systemctl is-enabled httpd.service >/dev/null || echo "Service not enabled"
systemctl is-active httpd.service >/dev/null || echo "Service not active"
systemctl is-failed httpd.service >/dev/null && echo "Service is failed"
```

Comment: Thank your @RoVo. Ok I made the correction as suggested. BUT my originalscript (the first one) works in its original form as well ... what is the difference between if [ "$(cmd)" != "active" ] instead if [ "cmd" != "active" ] ? Could you please explain ? Regarding || and &&. In the first test condition I would like to check if the service status is different than active, so if it is in inactive state the conditions is true that's why the && or did i get it somehow wrong ?

Comment: your original runs, but it is not doing what you intend. It will **never** be active, because it's comparing "active" with the string "cmd"

Answer (score 1):

As @RoVo says, be careful with your logic. You probably want

```
if [[ ! ("$STATE" = "active" && "SUBSTATE" = "running") ]]
```

note the use of bash's `[[ ... ]]`

or more portably

```
case "$STATE,$SUBSTATE" in
    "active,running") echo ok ;;
                   *) echo not ok ;;
esac
```